# Changing a circle's size with UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios, cashapelayer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I'm drawing a simple circle in the center of the screen:

```
int radius = 100;

- (void)addCircle {
    self.circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    self.circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius)
                                             cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
    self.circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-radius,
                                  CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)-radius);

    self.circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    self.circle.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.circle.lineWidth = 5;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.circle];
}
```

Using the pinch gesture, I allow the user to increase/decrease the radius of the shape:

```
- (void)scale:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {    
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if (gestureRecognizer.scale < lastScale) {
            --radius;
        }
        else if (gestureRecognizer.scale > lastScale) {
            ++radius;
        }
        // Center the shape in self.view
        self.circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-radius, CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)-radius);

        self.circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius) cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
    }

    lastScale = gestureRecognizer.scale;
}
```

However, the circle doesn't stay dead center. Instead, it bounces around the middle and doesn't settle until the gesture finishes.

Does anyone know why this is happening and if so, how I can prevent it?

Comment: CALayer.position defaults to its centre, not its top-left, and corresponds to UIView.center (both determined by CALayer.anchorPoint). Get rid of `-radius`.

Comment: @tc. Thanks, but without -radius it places the top left of the circle in the center: http://imgur.com/LBMf6

Comment: You're never setting the layer's frame. Try getting rid of `-radius` and using `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:(CGRect){{-radius,-radius},{2*radius,2*radius}}]`. You should also be using `self.view.bounds`; the view's frame is in its superview's coordinate system.

Comment: Did you try using transform property to change the scale instead of redrawing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code.  As @tc. said, you're not setting the shape layer's frame (or bounds).  The default layer size is `CGSizeZero`, which is why you're having to offset the layer's position by the radius every time you change the radius.

Also, the `position` and `path` properties of a shape layer are animatable.  So by default, when you change them, Core Animation will animate them to their new values.  The path animation is contributing to your unwanted behavior.

Also, you should set the layer's position or frame based on `self.view.bounds`, not `self.view.frame`, because the layer's position/frame is the coordinate system of `self.view`, not the coordinate system of `self.view.superview`.  This will matter if `self.view` is the top-level view and you support interface autorotation.

I would suggest revising how you're implementing this.  Make `radius` a `CGFloat` property, and make setting the property update the layer's `bounds` and `path`:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *circle;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat radius;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)setRadius:(CGFloat)radius {
    _radius = radius;
    self.circle.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    self.circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.circle.bounds].CGPath;
}
```

If you really want to force the radius to be an integer, I suggest internally tracking it as a float anyway, because the user interaction is smoother if it's a float.  Just round it in a temporary variable before creating the `CGRect` for the bounds and path:

```
    CGFloat intRadius = roundf(radius);
    self.circle.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2 * intRadius, 2 * intRadius);
    self.circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.circle.bounds].CGPath;
```

In `addCircle`, just set the `radius` property and let that setter take care of setting the layer's bounds and path.  Also defer setting the layer's position until the system's layout phase.  That way, you'll reposition the circle in the center again after an interface rotation.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addCircle];
}

- (void)addCircle {
    self.circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    self.circle.fillColor = nil;
    self.circle.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.circle.lineWidth = 5;
    self.radius = 100;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.circle];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
}
```

Finally, to handle a pinch gesture, just set the new radius to the old radius times the gesture's scale.  The `radius` setter will take care of updating the layer's path and bounds.  Then reset the gesture's scale to 1.  This is simpler than tracking the gesture's prior scale.  Also, use `CATransaction` to disable animation of the `path` property.

```
- (IBAction)pinchGestureWasRecognized:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [CATransaction begin]; {
        [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
        self.radius *= recognizer.scale;
        recognizer.scale = 1;
    } [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Comment: What a fantastically comprehensive answer. Thank you.

Comment: Kudos to the last piece of code with the block braces. Beautiful coding style.